# Declaratively build expression-tree rooted in a node of any type

Tags: lambda, expression-trees

MSDN say:

> The compiler can also build an
>   expression tree for you. A
>   compiler-generated expression tree is
>   always rooted in a node of type
>   Expression<TDelegate>; that is, its
>   root node represents a lambda
>   expression.

But what if I want to build an expression tree rooted in a node of type MethodCallExpression, BinaryExpression, etc.? And don't want to do this manually.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to declare 2 helper functions

```
public Expression GetBody(Expression<Action> lambda)
{
    return lambda.Body;
}

public Expression GetBody<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>> lambda)
{
    return lambda.Body;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
var e1 = (MethodCallExpression)GetBody(() => this.FunA());
var e2 = (ConstantExpression)GetBody(() => 4 + 5);
var e3 = (BinaryExpression)GetBody(() => a + b);
```